# Why when I try to remove non-breaking space from the string, I do not get the expected result?

Tags: java, string, encryption

I am writing code to create a cipher text using first a Transposition, then a substitution. So far, what I have done run fine (no substitution yet), except that the text obtained from the transposition contains non-breaking spaces.

After searching online, one of the solutions is to use `text.replace("\u00A0", "")`, which I use in my code, but it does not help me remove those non-breaking spaces. Your help and suggestions will be very appreciated. I am using Java with Netbeans IDE 7.4.

```
public class Cipher {

    static java.util.HashMap<String, String> HMOperators = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
    public static char[] Alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static int locateindex = 0;

    static int[] WhiteSpaceSeparator = new int[100];

    public static String TCipher(String text) 
    {

        char[] stringtoCharArray = text.toCharArray();
        char ch;

        int loc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) 
        {
            ch = stringtoCharArray[i];

            if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch)) 
        {
            WhiteSpaceSeparator[loc] = i;
        }
        loc++;

        }

        text = text.trim();
        String PlainTextNoSpace = text.replaceAll(" ", "");

        char[] charArray = PlainTextNoSpace.toCharArray();

        int NewIndexArray[] = {2, 7, 5, 3, 0, 4, 6, 1};

        int Rows = 6;
        int Cols = 8;

        char TArray[][] = new char[Rows][Cols];

        int i = 0;


        for (int row = 0; row <= 5; row++) 
        {
             if (i == charArray.length) 
             {
                break;
             }
             TArray[row][NewIndexArray[0]] = charArray[i];  //@ column number index == 2

             if ((i + 1) == charArray.length) 
             {
                break;
             }
             TArray[row][NewIndexArray[1]] = charArray[i + 1]; //@ column number index == 7

             if ((i + 2) == charArray.length) 
             {
               break;
             }
             TArray[row][NewIndexArray[2]] = charArray[i + 2]; //5

             if ((i + 3) == charArray.length) 
             {
                break;
             }
             TArray[row][NewIndexArray[3]] = charArray[i + 3]; //3

            if ((i + 4) == charArray.length) 
            {
                break;
            }
            TArray[row][NewIndexArray[4]] = charArray[i + 4]; //0

            if ((i + 5) == charArray.length) 
            {
                break;
            }
            TArray[row][NewIndexArray[5]] = charArray[i + 5]; //4

           if ((i + 6) == charArray.length) 
            {
                break;
            }
           TArray[row][NewIndexArray[6]] = charArray[i + 6]; //6

            if ((i + 7) == charArray.length) 
            {
                break;
            }
            TArray[row][NewIndexArray[7]] = charArray[i + 7]; //1

            i = i + 8;

        }

        //printing the new 2d array with columns organized in increasing order
        //the new plain text has to be read from the firt column (column 0) to the last one (column 7)
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 6; rows++) 
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) 
            {
                System.out.print(TArray[rows][col]);
            }

        }

        //Reading the new plain test per column
        char[] NewTChar = new char[Rows * Cols];

        int k = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) 
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (int rows = 0; rows < 6; rows++) 
            {
                ch = TArray[rows][col];
                NewTChar[k] = ch;  //storing all the columns into a 1d array to obtain a new text (new cipher)

                k++;

            }

        }

        int n = 0;

        String SeconPlainText = new String(NewTChar);

        SeconPlainText = SeconPlainText.trim();

        SeconPlainText = SeconPlainText.replace("\u00A0", "");  //It does not work, I am not sure why

        System.out.println(SeconPlainText);  

        System.out.println(SeconPlainText);

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(SeconPlainText);//it seems like the string is only one token
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());  //it prints the whole string, instead of each token
        }
        int a = st.countTokens();

        return SeconPlainText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String PlainText = "Machines take me by surprise with great frequency";

        String Ttext = TCipher(PlainText);

        // SCipher(Ttext);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problematic input? It's probably not `\u00A0`.

Comment: Non-braking is what happens when you crash your car into something, I think you meant non-breaking :-)

Comment: Side note: In Java, variable names should be `camelCase` (lower-case first letter). Many of your variables are `TitleCase`, which confuses Java programmers.

Comment: It strikes me that if you don't want non-breaking spaces in your output, you need to re-evaluate your transposition method. Simply substituting them after the event isn't going to be helpful. It may also mean you can't reverse your encryption (since you don't have these missing elements)l.

Answer (score 0):

I actually edited one of my for loops such that I have to force to store an actual white space character when a non-breaking space is encountered. Thus, when the char array is converted into a string, I can later remove the white space from the string using the text.replace(" ",""); Now, it works as expected. However, in the IDE (Netbeans), "isJavaLetter" is crossed out. I am not sure if it means it is deprecated, but it helped me do what I want. Below is my updated for loop:

```
 for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) 
 {
        System.out.println();
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 6; rows++) 
        {
            ch = TArray[rows][col];

            if(Character.isJavaLetter(ch))//

                NewTChar[k] = ch;  //storing all the columns into a 1d array to obtain a new text (new cipher)
            else
                    NewTChar[k] =' ';   //storing an actual white space character
            k++;

        }

 }
```